# Are all algebraic integers with absolute value 1 roots of unity?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-number-theory

If we have an algebraic number $\alpha$ with (complex) absolute value $1$, it does not follow that $\alpha$ is a root of unity (i.e., that $\alpha^n = 1$ for some $n$).  For example, $(3/5 + 4/5 i)$ is not a root of unity.

But if we assume that $\alpha$ is an algebraic integer with absolute value $1$, does it follow that $\alpha$ is a root of unity?

---

I know that if all conjugates of $\alpha$ have absolute value $1$, then $\alpha$ is a root of unity by the argument below:

The minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ over $\mathbb{Z}$ is $\prod_{i=1}^d (x-\alpha_i)$, where the $\alpha_i$ are just the conjugates of $\alpha$.  Then $\prod_{i=1}^d (x-\alpha_i^n)$ is a polynomial over $\mathbb{Z}$ with $\alpha^n$ as a root.  It also has degree $d$, and all roots have absolute value $1$.  But there can only be finitely many such polynomials (since the coefficients are integers with bounded size), so we get that $\alpha^n=\sigma(\alpha)$ for some Galois conjugation $\sigma$. If $\sigma^m(\alpha) = \alpha$, then $\alpha^{n^m} = \alpha$.

Thus $\alpha^{n^m - 1} = 1$.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

No. There are algebraic integers on the unit circle which aren't roots of unity.

[This paper](http://ramanujan.math.trinity.edu/rdaileda/research/papers/p1.pdf) by Ryan Daileda provides some useful information and references.

Also see [Salem numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salem_number).

Comment: Thank you!  That's an excellent reference and paper (with the added benefit of being very clear and just 3 pages long)!  I'm curious now what is the smallest extension containing such a unit.

Comment: What do you mean by smallest extension?  Extension of least degree?  Least discriminant (in abs. value)?

Comment: @Robin In the paper by Ryan Daileda, he propesed at very first that the unit group $U_k$ of a number field $k$ is a finitely generated group. May I ask why?

Comment: @WembleyInter the fact that $U_k$ is finitely generated is part of Dirichlet's unit theorem.  It is part of the easier direction.  Dirichlet's unit theorem says $U_k$ has rank $r(k) + s(k) - 1$, where $r(k)$ and $s(k)$ are defined in Daileda's paper (number of real embeddings and number of pairs of complex embeddings, respectively). To show $U_k$ has rank at most $r(k) + s(k) - 1$ is much easier than showing the rank is exactly $r(k) + s(k) - 1$,  and getting that finite upper bound is enough to see that $U_k$ is finitely generated.

Answer (score 64):

Let $x$ be an algebraic number with absolute value $1$. Then $x$ and its complex conjugate $\overline{x} = 1/x$ have the same minimal polynomial. Writing $f(T)$ for the minimal polynomial of $x$ over $\mathbb{Q}$, with degree $n$, the polynomials $T^nf(1/T)$ and $f(T)$ are irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$ with root $\overline{x}$, so the polynomials are equal up to a scaling factor: $$T^nf(1/T) = cf(T).$$ Setting $T = 1$, $f(1) = cf(1)$.

Assuming $x$ is not rational (i.e., $x$ is not $1$ or $-1$), $f$ has degree greater than $1$, so $f(1)$ is nonzero and thus $c = 1$. Therefore $$T^nf(1/T) = f(T),$$ so $f(T)$ has symmetric coefficients. In particular, its constant term is $1$. Moreover, the roots of $f(T)$ come in reciprocal pairs (since $1$ and $-1$ are not roots), so $n$ is even.

Partial conclusion: an algebraic number other than $1$ or $-1$ which has absolute value $1$ has even degree over $\mathbb{Q}$ and its minimal polynomial has constant term $1$. In particular, if $x$ is an algebraic integer then it must be a unit.

There are no examples of algebraic integers with degree $2$ and absolute value $1$ that are not roots of unity, since a real quadratic field has no elements on the unit circle besides $1$ and $-1$ and the units in an imaginary quadratic field are all roots of unity (and actually are only $1$ and $-1$ except for $\mathbb{Q}(i)$ and $\mathbb{Q}(\omega)$). Thus the smallest degree $x$ could have over $\mathbb{Q}$ is $4$ and there are examples with degree $4$: the polynomial $$x^4 - 2x^3 - 2x + 1$$ has two roots on the unit circle and two real roots (one between $0$ and $1$ and the other greater than $1$).

Comment: Thank you; I appreciate the thorough explanation.  In my comment above, I was simply wondering about the extension of least degree, curious if degree 4 was enough-- as you've shown it is.  Checking various symmetric polynomials in Wolfram Alpha, I see there are many such unimodular units.  x^4-3x^3+3x^2-3x+1 has discriminant just -275.

Comment: How to see that a root in the explicit polynomial you mentioned is of modulus 1?

Comment: @Student see the first paragraph of https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/galoistheory/numbersoncircle.pdf.

Comment: +1! A beautiful paper with beautiful pictures.

Comment: For one's information, the two roots are $\dfrac{1-\sqrt{3}}{2} \pm \dfrac{\sqrt[4]{3}}{\sqrt{2}}{\rm i}$ (using Mathematica).

Answer (score 25):

The answer to your question is no - not all algebraic integers with absolute value 1 are roots of unity - as you may have learned by now from the [2005 paper of Daileda](http://ramanujan.math.trinity.edu/rdaileda/research/papers/p1.pdf) that was referenced in the answer supplied by Robin Chapman. However, you should be aware that **Daileda has in fact rediscovered** these simple folklore results on unimodular units. These results are probably at least a half-century old - if not much older. Indeed, I recall reading similar results in papers published  by Iwasawa in the fifties or sixties. I don't have the time now to locate said Iwasawa reference, but here is another reference that suffices to prove my point. This [1979 paper of Nakahata](http://ci.nii.ac.jp/naid/110000010754/en) includes the same results and the same simple proofs found in Daileda's paper. Moreover, Nakahata places these results naturally into a more general context. Thus I highly recommend that you consult Nakahata's paper in addition to Daileda's. I've appended its Zbl review below.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, it's nice to have another reference and to see a more general result.

Answer (score 9):

Let me first mention an example in Character Theory. Let $G$ be a finite group of order $n$ and assume $\rho$ is a representation with character $\chi:=\chi_\rho$ which is defined by $\chi(g)=Tr(\rho(g))$. Since $G$ is a finite group then, by invoking facts from linear algebra, one can show $\chi(g)\in\mathbb{Z}[\zeta_n]$. For abelian groups, it is easy to see $\chi(g)$ is a root of unity, when $\chi$ is irreducible, but what about non-abelian groups? In other words let $|\chi(g)|=1$, what can we say about $\chi(g)$?

This relates to your question. Let assume $K/\mathbb{Q}$ be an abelian Galois extension inside $\mathbb{C}$, and take an algebraic integer $\alpha\in\mathcal{O}_K$ such that $|\alpha|=1$, then for any $\sigma\in Gal(K/\mathbb{Q})$ we have 
$$
|\sigma(\alpha)|^2=\sigma(\alpha)\overline{\sigma(\alpha)}
$$
Since $K/\mathbb{Q}$ is abelian then $\overline{\sigma(\alpha)}=\sigma(\overline{\alpha})$ so 
$$
|\sigma(\alpha)|^2=\sigma(|\alpha|)=1
$$
Then norm of all its conjugate is one so it must be a root of unity. This answer to the question was posed, therefore if $|\chi(g)|=1$ then $\chi(g)$ is root of unity.

Answer (score 4):

Notice however that if all roots of a polynomial with integer coefficients lie on the unit complex circle (i.e., all roots z have |z|=1), then, by a theorem of Kronecker, these roots are indeed roots of unit.

Comment: It's a good comment, but appears to be a comment rather than an answer.

Comment: Agree with Goos. This is a very good argument. But you should follow up on it by giving an example. Given that the question is over 4 years old, I don't think that a hint is any longer appropriate.

Comment: Can you state the theorem, please?

Comment: @Ninja You can find it in a really short way here (it is kindof included in the proof): https://crypto.stanford.edu/pbc/notes/numberfield/kummerlemma.html (all the roots are conjugate to each other).

Comment: I am checking it, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

As pointed out above, an algebraic integer with absolute value equal to 1 does not have to be a root of unity. But if *all the conjugates* of the algebraic integer have absolute value 1, then it is indeed the case.

Let $\alpha$ be an algebraic integer with minimum polynomial $f\in \mathbb{Z}[X]$, which is monic and say of degree $n$. We can assume $n \geq 2$ otherwise $\alpha \in \{-1,1\}$. Assume *all* the roots of $f$ have absolute value 1. Let us concentrate on the coefficient of $X^i$: the sum of the roots taking $i$ of them each time is in absolute value bounded by ${n}\choose{i}$ by the triangle inequality. Thus the coefficient of $X^i$ is in absolute value bounded by ${n}\choose{i}$, hence for any $n$ there are only *finitely many* algebraic integers of degree $n$ such that all conjugates have absolute value $1$, since there are only finitely many polynomials in $\mathbb{Z}[X]$ with given bounded coefficients.
Next, consider the powers of $\alpha$. They are all algebraic integers of degree at most $n$, and furthermore all their conjugates also have absolute value $1$ since the Galois actions map powers of $\alpha$ to powers of its conjugates. Thus, the powers of $\alpha$ are elements of a *finite* set. This implies $\alpha$ must be a root of unity.

In the case of a finite group $G$, $g \in G$ and complex (not necessarily irreducible) character $\chi$ with $|\chi(g)|=1$ all the Galois conjugates of the algebraic number $\chi(g)$ also have absolute value $1$. Let $n=o(g)$ and $K=\Omega_{\mathbb{Q}}^{X^n-1} \subseteq \mathbb{C}$ the splitting field. Let $\mathfrak{G}=Gal(K/\mathbb{Q}) \cong (\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^*$. If $\sigma \in \mathfrak{G}$ and $\varepsilon$ is an $n$th-root of unity, then $\sigma(\varepsilon)=\varepsilon^m$, for some $m \in \mathbb{Z}$, with gcd$(m,n)=1$. Now, $\chi(g)=\varepsilon_1 + \cdots + \varepsilon_{\chi(1)}$, a sum of $n$th-roots of unity. Hence, $\sigma(\chi(g))=\varepsilon_1^m + \cdots + \varepsilon_{\chi(1)}^m=\chi(g^m)$. Note that $\mathfrak{G}$ is abelian and that the restriction of complex conjugation to $K$ induces an element of $\mathfrak{G}$ of order $2$. Hence, $|\sigma(\chi(g))|^2=\sigma(\chi(g)) \cdot \overline{\sigma(\chi(g))}=\sigma(\chi(g)) \cdot \sigma(\overline{\chi(g)})=\sigma(|\chi(g)|^2)=\sigma(1)=1$, which yields $|\chi(g^m)|=1$.

Answer (score 3):

Following the paper provided by Robin Chapman, I give an explicit algebraic integer that is not a root of unity:

Let $\alpha = \left(1-\dfrac{1}{2}\sqrt[3]{3}-\dfrac{1}{2}\sqrt[3]{3^2}\right) + \left(\dfrac{1}{2}\sqrt[6]{3}-\dfrac{1}{2}\sqrt[6]{3^5}\right)i$, then $|\alpha| = 1$, and $\alpha$ is a root of $x^6 - 6x^5 + 6x^4 + 10x^3 + 6x^2 - 6x + 1$ (thanks to Mathematica), but $\alpha$ is not a root of unity because that polynomial is not a cyclotomic polynomial.