# Is an algebraic integer all of whose conjugates have absolute value 1 a root of unity?

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Are all algebraic integers with absolute value 1 roots of unity?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4323/are-all-algebraic-integers-with-absolute-value-1-roots-of-unity)

Let $\alpha$ be an algebraic integer.
Suppose that all the roots of its minimal polynomial have absolute value 1.
Is $\alpha$ a root of unity?

Comment: I assume you mean all the roots of its minimal polynomial except possibly $\alpha$, correct?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4323/are-all-algebraic-integers-with-absolute-value-1-roots-of-unity?rq=1

Comment: Dear Makoto, Yes, this is a classical theorem of Kronecker.  See @Jack Schmidt's link, and the MO question and answers linked there.  Regards,

Comment: @MattE Could you provide a link for the MO thread? I don't see one in Jack's link. The question in Jack's link has weaker hypotheses than Makoto's question - Makoto assumes all roots of $\alpha$'s minimal polynomial has absolute value $1$, not just $\alpha$ itself.

Comment: @Ragib: Dear Ragib, See the link to MO in the last comment posted to that question.  Regards,

Comment: @MattE Ahh, I hadn't expanded to see the hidden comments. Cheers.

Comment: Here is another link     http://www2.ucy.ac.cy/~damianou/kronecker.pdf

Comment: Meta discussion: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4745/should-this-question-be-closed-as-duplicate