# On a certain property of units in the cyclotomic number field of an odd prime order

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

Let $l$ be an odd prime number and $\zeta$ be a primitive $l$-th  root of unity in $\mathbb{C}$.
Let $K = \mathbb{Q}(\zeta)$.
Let $A$ be the ring of algebraic integers in $K$.
Let $\epsilon$ be a unit of $A$.

My question: Is $\epsilon/\bar{\epsilon}$ a root of unity?

**Motivation and Effort**
This is clear from [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/174880/is-an-algebraic-integer-all-of-whose-conjugates-have-absolute-value-1-a-root-of).

Comment: What's the reason for the downvotes? Unless you tell me, I can't improve my question.

Comment: (I edited your comment into what I think you meant to write. Beware of [double negatives](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_negative)!)

Answer (score 2):

*Yes*.  In the notation of [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/175330/221), the ratio $\epsilon/\overline{\epsilon}$ lies in $U^-$, which is a finite group (as explained in the linked answer).

Answer (score 0):

Yes: By [Kummer's Lemma](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/gradnumthy/kummer.pdf), $\epsilon/\bar{\epsilon}$ is a unit in A as it is a power of a $l$-th root of unity