# Real units of the cyclotomic number fields of an odd prime order

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

Let $l$ be an odd prime number and $\zeta$ be a primitive $l$-th root of unity in $\mathbb{C}$.
Let $K = \mathbb{Q}(\zeta)$.
Let $A$ be the ring of algebraic integers in $K$.
Let $\epsilon$ be a unit of $A$.

My question: Is the following proposition true? If yes, how would you prove this?

**Proposition**
There exists a real unit $\eta$ such that $\epsilon = \zeta^g\eta$.

*Related questions:*

[On a certain property of units in the cyclotomic number field of an odd prime order](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/175020/on-a-certain-property-of-units-in-the-cyclotomic-number-field-of-an-odd-prime-or)

[The group of roots of unity in the cyclotomic number field of an odd prime order](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/175039/the-group-of-roots-of-unity-in-the-cyclotomic-number-field-of-an-odd-prime-order)

[Is there a purely imaginary unit in the cyclotomic number field of an odd prime degree?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/175006/is-there-a-purely-imaginary-unit-in-the-cyclotomic-number-field-of-an-odd-prime)

Answer (score 7):

The proposition is true (it probably goes back to Kummer), and here is a proof:

Let $U$ be the group of units in the cyclotomic field, and $U^+$ denote the group of units in its totally real subfield.  By the unit theorem, $U^+$ has finite index in $U$.

Consider $\epsilon/\overline{\epsilon}$.  This lies in the group $U^-$ of units
such that $\overline{u} = u^{-1}$.  Since $U^+ \cap U^- = \{ \pm 1\}$, 
and $U/U^+$ is finite, we see that $U^-$ is finite.  By the answer to another of 
your questions, $U^-$ thus has order dividing $2l$, and so $U^-/\{\pm 1\}$ has order $l$.  In particular, it has odd order, and each of its elements is a square of some other element (a general property of finite abelian groups of odd order). So we may write
$\epsilon/\overline{\epsilon} = \pm u^2$ for some element $u \in U^-$.  Without loss of generality, we may further assume that $u$ has odd order, so that $u = \zeta^g$ for some $g$.

Then $\overline{\epsilon u^{-1}} = \overline{\epsilon} u = \pm \epsilon u^{-1}$.
If the sign is $+1$, then we see that $\epsilon u^{-1}$ is a real unit, and we are done.
If the sign is $-1$, then $\epsilon u^{-1}$ is purely imaginary, which is not possible (see [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/175311/221)).