# number of roots of unity which satisfy a given polynomial

Tags: matrices, roots-of-unity

Let $A$ be a matrix over $\mathbb{R}$ and $p_A(x)$ its characteristic polynomial. Is there an easy way to find out how many of the roots of $p_A(x)$ are roots of unity?

Fixing a positive integer $k$, the multiplicity of 1 as a root of $p_{A^k}(x)$ is the number of roots of unity of order dividing $k$ which satisfy $p_A(x)$, which gives some of the information. If $A$ is normal, then I can simply count the multiplicity of 1 in $p_{AA^*}(x)$, but this is not true for general matrices.

I'm mainly interested in matrices of order 4, for which there is a formula for the roots. I want to run some computer program to count the number of roots of unity, and I prefer not to use division and square\cube roots to avoid (as far as I can) precision errors. There is, on the other hand, a way to check how many real\complex roots a quartic polynomial has by using only polynomial functions of its coefficients, and the question is if there is something similar to count the roots of unity.

Answer (score 1):

First, you don't need your matrix $A$ in this problem, only the polynomial $p$, which I will call $f$ instead since $p$ will be a prime number later.
I call $S_n$ the set of common roots of $f$ and $x^n-1$ and $S_\infty$ the union of all sets $S_n$.

For fixed $d$, your problem is easy: the roots of unity of order $d$ are the roots of $x^d-1$, thus the elements of $S_d$ are exactly the roots of $\mathrm{gcd} (f, x^d-1)$.

For variable $d$, you can find all the roots of $p$ lying in the complex unit circle $\mathbb{U}$: use the parametrization of the circle by $\mathbb P^1(\mathbb R)$ given by $t \mapsto q(t) = (\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}, \frac{2t}{1+t^2})$ and write $f(q(t)) = u(t) + i v(t)$. The roots of $f$ on the unit circle are exactly the images by $q$ of the common roots of $u$ and $v$, computed as the roots of $\gcd (u, v)$. Out of this list, the roots of unity [are algebraic integers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4323/are-all-algebraic-integers-with-absolute-value-1-roots-of-unity). But not all algebraic integers are roots of unity!
However, once you have this list of candidates, it should be easier to search for roots of unity.

Comment: This is a nice approach. The problem is that $u(t),v(t)$ are not polynomials. If on the other hand we multiply by $(1+t^2)^{\deg(f)}$, then they become polynomials but with degree $2\deg(f)$. Is there a way to bound $\deg(gcd(u,v))$ in this case?

Comment: Another idea I got just now is that if $q(t)$ is a root of unity, then $\overline{q(t)} = q(-t)$ also is. So you might want to use $\mathrm{gcd} (u(t), v(t), v(-t))$ (since $u$ is an even function). OTOH, a criterion on $t$ for deciding when $q(t)$ is a root of unity is likely to involve Chebyshev polynomials and a bit unwieldy.