# If a complex number with unit modulus is a root of a monic polynomial with integer coefficients, is it a root of unity?

Tags: ring-theory, algebraic-number-theory

The title says pretty much everything:

> We have $z\in\mathbb{C}$ such that $\|z\|=1$ and a monic polynomial $p\in\mathbb{Z}[x]$ such that $p(z)=0$.
>   Is it true that for some $n\in\mathbb{N}$, $z^n=1$?

My thoughts about it: assume that $z=e^{\pi i\alpha}$ and $z$ is not a root of unity, i.e. $\alpha\not\in\mathbb{Q}$.
Then $\alpha$ has to be a trascendental number: otherwise, by the [Gelfond-Schneider theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gelfond%E2%80%93Schneider_theorem), $z$ is a trascendental number. But obviously this is far from closing the question: for instance, $\frac{3+4i}{5}$ is a complex number with unit modulus, and $\frac{1}{\pi}\arctan\left(\frac{4}{3}\right)$ is a trascendental number, but there is no monic polynomial with integer coefficients having $\frac{3+4i}{5}$ as a root. So, what is the good way to go for proving the claim above, since I believe it is true? Counter-examples are welcome as well, obviously.

Comment: If $z^\alpha = 1$ where $\alpha$ is irrational and $z \neq 1$, it seems pretty hard to believe that an INTEGER combination of non-negative powers of $z$ could possibly be 0. However proof eludes me. Nice question!

Comment: The answer is no, and the question has been discussed here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4323/are-all-algebraic-integers-with-absolute-value-1-roots-of-unity

Comment: @MannyReyes: thank you so much, I am closing the question.

Comment: @Manny: Good job digging up that duplicate (using the link elsewhere)! Jack, [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1373128/11619) I gave $u=\sqrt2-1+i\sqrt{2\sqrt2-2}$ as a specific example of an algebraic integer on the unit circle that is not a root of unity. Finding such things is not too hard. Pick a real part that is an algebraic integer $\in(0,1)$, and find a matching imaginary part. With any luck the minimal polynomial will have roots not on the unit circle. That then immediately implies that we don't have a root of unity for otherwise all the conjugates would have absolute value $1$.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen: thanks for the explicit counter-example, too.