# How to prove that a complex number is not a root of unity?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory, complex-numbers, field-theory

> $\frac35+i\frac45$ is not a root of unity though its absolute value is $1$.

Suppose I don't have a calculator to calculate out its argument then how do I prove it?

Is there any approach from abstract algebra or can it be done simply using complex numbers?

Any help will be truly appreciated.

Comment: Since $\frac 35 + i\cdot \frac 45$ is not an algebraic integer in $\mathbb Q(i)$ (since the set of algebraic integers in $\mathbb Q(i)$ is precisely $\mathbb Z[i]$), this cannot be a root of unity.

Comment: can you please give me a link where I can get a detailed explanation?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_integer for the definition of an algebraic integer. For the proof that $\mathbb Z[i]$ is the set of algebraic integers in $\mathbb Q(i)$ see any book on algebraic number theory; e.g. Algebraic Number Theory by Jürgen Neukirch: In I.(1.2) he shows that $\mathbb Z[i]$ is Euklidean and in particular a UFD. In the discussion after I.(2.4) he shows more generally that every UFD is integrally closed in its fraction field. This is what you need here.

Comment: Unfortunately, it is not true that all algebraic integers on the unit circle are roots of unity, see e.g. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4323/are-all-algebraic-integers-with-absolute-value-1-roots-of-unity

Comment: The (monic) minimal polynomial of $\frac{3+4i}{5}$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ has a non-integer coefficient. It follows that $\frac{3+4i}{5}$ cannot be the root of a cyclotomic polynomial, hence it cannot be a root of unity.

Answer (score 28):

$(3+4i)^2 = -7 + 24i = (3+4i)+5(-2+4i)$

With this you can easily prove by induction that for every positive integer $n \ge 1$ there are integers $a_n,b_n$ such that $(3+4i)^n = (3+4i) + 5(a_n+b_n i)$.

In particular, since $4$ is not a multiple of $5$, its imaginary part cannot vanish, so $(3+4i)^n$ can't be a real number when $n \ge 1$.

---

Here we were lucky that $(3+4i)^n$ mod $5$ is $1$-periodic (that $3+4i = 1 \pmod {2-i}$), in general you can get a cyclic behaviour with larger periods, so it can be a bit longer to write down, but the method works just as well.

---

Suppose $(a+ib)/c$ is on the unit circle, with $a$ and $b$ coprime.

First, note that if $c$ is even then so are $a$ and $b$ (because $a^2+b^2=c^2$ and squares are congruent to $0$ or $1$ mod $4$), and we supposed they weren't, so $c$ must be odd.
Also, $a$ and $b$ are coprime with $c$ (if $a$ shared a prime factor with $c$, $b$ would also have it).

Now we look at things modulo $(c)$.
Let $j \in \Bbb Z/(c)$ such that $a+jb=0$ (this has a unique solution because $b$ is invertible mod $c$).

Then $j^2 = -1 \pmod c$ ($0 = (a+jb)(a-jb) = a^2-j^2b^2$ and since $a^2=-b^2$ and $-b^2$ is invertible, we must have $j^2+1 = 0$), and we can check that the map $\phi : \Bbb Z[i]/(c) \to (\Bbb Z/(c))^2$ defined by $\phi(x+iy) = (x+jy,x-jy)$ is a ring morphism.

If $\phi(x+iy)=0$ then $x+jy=x-jy=0$ from which you get $2x=2y=0$. But $c$ is odd so $2$ is invertible, and so this implies $x=y=0$. This shows that $\phi$ is injective, and since we're dealing with finite rings, it is an isomorphism of rings.
(note that there can be *many* isomorphisms between those two rings, but this  one in particular is the useful one to study $(a+ib)^n$)

Now we have $\phi(a+ib) = (a+jb,a-jb) = (0,a-jb) = (0,2a)$ : Multiplying by $(a+ib)$ is annihilating the first component and multiplying the second by $2a$.
And so $\phi((a+ib)^n) = (0^n, (2a)^n)$.

Since $2a$ is invertible mod $c$, the second component is periodic. The first component stays at $0$ from $n \ge 1$, and so the sequence $(\phi((a+ib)^n))_{n \ge 1}$ is periodic. Since $\phi$ is an isomorphism, the sequence $((a+ib)^n \pmod c)_{n \ge 1}$ is also periodic.

Conjugation in $\Bbb Z[i]/(c)$ is translated into the automorphism $(u,v) \mapsto (v,u)$ of $(\Bbb Z/(c))^2$. 
An element is "real mod $c$" if and only if it is fixed by conjugation. In the $\Bbb Z[i]/(c)$ world this is when the coefficient of $i$ is $0$ (as usual), in the $(\Bbb Z/(c))^2$ world this is when both components are equal.

In particular, since the first component of $\phi((a+ib)^n)$ for $n \ge 1$ is always $0$, it can only be real mod $c$ if both components are $0$. But (unless $c=\pm 1 $ !!) this is impossible because $2a$ is invertible and so its powers can't be zero. So $(a+ib)^n$ is real mod $c$ only when $n=0$ and never again.

Equivalently, this means that the imaginary part of $(a+ib)^n$ is never again a multiple of $c$, and this implies that $(a+ib)^n$ is never real again.

Answer (score 15):

The minimal polynomial of $\frac35+\frac45i$ is quadratic. If it were a primitive $n$th root of unity, the degree should be $\phi(n)$. Hence only few $n$ are possible ($n=3$, $n=4$), but of course this is neither a third nor a fourth root of unity.

Comment: Why primitive?.

Comment: @user26857 a number that is an $m$th root of unity is a primitive $n$th root of unity for some $n\mid m$, so this is no restriction after all

Answer (score 6):

If $(3+4i)^n=5^n$ then, in $\mathbb Z[i]$, we have $(2+i)^{2n}=(2+i)^n(2-i)^n$ hence $(2+i)^{n}=(2-i)^n$.

But $2+i$ (and $2-i$, but we don't need it) is a prime element in $\mathbb Z[i]$ (why?), so we must have $2+i\mid 2-i$, impossible. (If $2-i=(2+i)(m+ni)$, then $2=2m-n$ and $-1=m+2n$, therefore $m=\frac35\notin\mathbb Z$.)

Answer (score 4):

Write $e^{i\theta} = \frac{3}{5} + i\frac{4}{5}$. Then $e^{ni\theta} = 1$ only if $\cos(n\theta) = 1$, that is, if
$$\cos(n\theta) = T_n(\cos\theta) = T_n\left(\frac{3}{5}\right) = 1$$
where $T_n$ is the $n$-th Chebyshev polynomial.

But the leading term of $T_n$ for $n > 0$ is $2^{n-1}$, thus the minimum denominator of any rational root of $T_n - 1$ must divide $2^{n-1}$. Since 5 does not, $T_n\left(\frac{3}{5}\right) - 1 \neq 0$ for all $n > 0$.

Answer (score 4):

Let $a=\frac{3}{5}+\frac{4}{5}i$. If $a$ were a root of unity, there would exist a positive integer $n$ so that

$$a^n-1=0.$$

Expressions of the form $x^n-1$ can be factored into products of [cyclotomic polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclotomic_polynomial):

$$x^n-1=\prod_{d|n}\Phi_d(x).$$

There are several properties of cyclotomic polynomials that are relevant here:

- $\Phi_d(x)\in\mathbb{Z}[x]$. That is, all its coefficients are integers.
- $\Phi_d(x)$ is monic, meaning that the coefficient of the highest-powered term is 1.
- $\Phi_d(x)$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}[x]$. That is, it cannot be factored into two non-constant polynomials with rational coefficients.

The minimal monic polynomial $p(x)\in\mathbb{Q}[x]$ for $a$ is readily calculated to be

$$p(x)=x^2-\frac{6}{5}x+1.$$

In other words, $p(x)$ is the lowest-powered monic polynomial with rational coefficients where $p(a)=0$. Because of the non-integer $-\frac{6}{5}$ coefficient, $p(x)\neq\Phi_d(x)$ for any positive integer $d$ and therefore $a$ is not a root of unity.

Answer (score 2):

We use the formula for $\tan  n t$ in terms of $\tan t$ (when $n\in\mathbb N$).

(1) For odd  prime $p$, let $ q=(p-1)/2.$  Let $x=\tan \pi/p.$ Then $0=\tan \pi=\tan p(\pi/p) = A(x)/B(x)$ where, for any $z,$  $$A(z)=\sum_{j=0}^q(-1)^j z^{2 j+1}\binom {p}{2 j + 1}$$ $$\text {and }\quad B(z)=\sum_{j=0}^q(-1)^j z^{ j}\binom {p}{2 j}.$$  By Eisenstein's Criterion, the polynomial $A(z)$ is irreducible over $\mathbb Q$, and $\deg(A(z))=p>1$,  so any solution of $A(z)=0$ is irrational. Since $A(\tan \pi/p)=A(x)=0,$ we have $$\tan \pi/p\not \in\mathbb Q.$$

(2) Assume $\tan \pi m/n \in\mathbb Q,$ where $m, n\in\mathbb Z^+$, with $\gcd (m,n)=1$, and $n$ is divisible by an odd prime $p.$ Let $r\in\mathbb Z$ such that $m r\equiv 1 \pmod n.$ Then $m r\pi/n=\pi (k+1/n)$ where $k\in Z$, so  $\tan m r \pi/n=\pm \tan \pi/n.$

By the formula for $\tan (\pi m/n)r$ in terms of $\tan \pi m/n,$ we have $\tan \pi/n\in\mathbb Q.$  Let $n=p s .$ By the formula for $\tan (\pi/n)s$ in terms of $\tan \pi/s,$ we have $\tan \pi/p\in\mathbb Q.$ This contradicts (1). Therefore $\tan \pi m/n\not \in\mathbb Q$.

(3) We can also show that  $\tan m 2^{-m}\pi\not \in\mathbb Q$ when $m,n \in\mathbb N$ with odd  $m$  and $n\geq 3$.

(4) Therefore if $z=\cos T+i \sin T$ is an $n$th root of $1$, for some $n\in \mathbb N$, and $z\not \in \{\exp (\pi i j/4) :j\in N\}$  then $\tan T\not \in\mathbb Q.$

In particular, if $\tan T=4/3,$ then $T\ne q\pi$ for any $q\in\mathbb Q,$ so $(3+4 i)/5$ is not an $n$th root of $1.$

Comment: I believe this result on $\tan \pi x\in Q$ goes back to the 18th century, which  precedes Eisenstein (1823-1852).

Answer (score 1):

In $\mathbb Z_5[i]$ : $(3+4i)(3+4i) = 3+4i$

$\forall n \ge 1$ : $(3+4i)^n \notin \Re$

$(3+4i)/5$ is not a root of unity.

Comment: Isn't this the same idea of the @mercio's answer?